# Factoring maps between noetherian rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be commutative noetherian rings, and let $f:A\to B$ be a ring map.

Can one always factor $f$ as $A\to C\to B$ where $C$ is a noetherian ring, $A\to C$ is flat, and $C \to B$ is surjective?

Comment: Why would you believe that is possible? Any reason behind it?